# "For dataset in total": Not applying to both train and test datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning

My for "dataset in total" is only applying to my test set, and is not altering the datapoints on my train set. Can someone help explain this?

```
total=[train,test]
for dataset in total:
    dataset.loc[dataset['Fare'] <= 18, 'Fare'] = 9
    dataset.loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 18) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 37.0042), 'Fare'] = 11
    dataset.loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 37.0042) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 63.3583), 'Fare'] = 22
    dataset.loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 63.3583) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 93.5), 'Fare'] = 33
    dataset.loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 93.5) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 120), 'Fare'] = 44
    dataset.loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 120) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 164.8667), 'Fare'] = 55
    dataset.loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 164.8667) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 263), 'Fare'] = 66
    dataset.loc[dataset['Fare'] > 263, 'Fare'] =77
total=[train,test]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas dataframes are mutable.
Read the following from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/overview.html):

> Mutability and copying of data All pandas data structures are
>   value-mutable (the values they contain can be altered) but not always
>   size-mutable. The length of a Series cannot be changed, but, for
>   example, columns can be inserted into a DataFrame. However, the vast
>   majority of methods produce new objects and leave the input data
>   untouched. In general we like to favor immutability where sensible.

You could change your code as follows:

```
total=[train,test]
for i in range(2):
    total[i].loc[dataset['Fare'] <= 18, 'Fare'] = 9
    total[i].loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 18) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 37.0042), 'Fare'] = 11
    total[i].loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 37.0042) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 63.3583), 'Fare'] = 22
    total[i].loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 63.3583) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 93.5), 'Fare'] = 33
    total[i].loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 93.5) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 120), 'Fare'] = 44
    total[i].loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 120) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 164.8667), 'Fare'] = 55
    total[i].loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 164.8667) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 263), 'Fare'] = 66
    total[i].loc[dataset['Fare'] > 263, 'Fare'] =77
# no need for this statement! total=[train,test]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the  well thought explanation!